# При потоке новых значений находить разность между последующем и предыдущем значениями

Tags: python, dict

Есть поток сообщений. Из каждого принятого сообщения я создаю словарь. Каждое сообщение проверяется на повторение ключа, если ключ повторяется, то в словарь я просто добавляю новое значение к этому же ключу. Таким образом словарь постоянно обновляется. Мне необходимо находить разность между последующем и предыдущем значением по каждому ключу отдельно во временном потоке. Вот часть изначального кода:

```
dict_ms = defaultdict(list)
        if key not in dict_msg :
            dict_msg[key] = [value]  
        else: 
            dict_msg[key].append(value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот это нужно?

```
else: 
    difference = value - dict_msg[key][-1]
    dict_msg[key].append(value)
```

Comment: Не совсем. Что-то типа этого, только что корректно работало:                                                                            for i in range(len(value)):
     for j in range(i+1, len(value)):
            g = (value)[j] - (value)[i]
             k[key] = [g]

Comment: Ничего не понял. Стоит показать пример

Comment: Дополнила вопрос.Надеюсь сейчас стало более понятно.

Comment: Нет, не стало. То, что я показал, подходит под ваш пример с двумя значениями, но что будет для трёх и более?  `но не забывая` - мы пока не знаем того, что можно забыть ;)

Comment: да ЧТО сделать-то? Приведите пример с недлинными числами, чтобы можно было увидеть нужный результат

Comment: Например: для ключа 1 приходят последовательно значения 3, 9, 7, 12. Что должно получиться на выходе?

Comment: на выход должно прийти: 6, -2,  5

Comment: Тогда что не устраивает в моём ответе? difference будет принимать эти значения

Comment: Все устраивает) Извините, что-то затупила.Спасибо большое!